# Sprite gets stuck between two sprites

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a Super Mario imitation on iOS using SpriteKit entirely. In this game I've created a wall that's consisting of different blocks, for some reason the player can stand in between those blocks even though there's literally no space to stand on. (see image below)

The playerSprite is using precise collision detections and has the physics body of a rectangle.

The blocks don't use precise collision detection and are a perfect square.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loMjo.jpg)

Here's the code concerning the physicsbody of the player:

```
func setupPhysics() {
    self.physicsBody!.mass = 0.02275555580854416
    self.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
    self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.brickBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.questionMarkBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.groundBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.solidBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.enemy.rawValue
    self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.brickBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.questionMarkBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.groundBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.solidBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.coin.rawValue | CollisionTypes.playerDetectionBlock.rawValue | CollisionTypes.enemy.rawValue
}
```

Here's the code concerning the blocks:

```
self.size = CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
self.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Solid Block")
self.texture!.filteringMode = .nearest
self.name = "SolidBlock"
self.position = position
self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.solidBlock.rawValue
self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
self.blendMode = .replace
```

Thank you already for helping me out!

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve], otherwise your question is considered off-topic here.

Comment: With floating point, you are going to always get a gab because of the way rounding is handled.  I would recommend combining all continuous blocks to form 1 body

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you very much, it’s kinda annoying that that’s the case but it works now :)